# Sort a column in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My column values looks like this.

```
Q1-2011   (1st quarter 2011 )
Q1-2011
Q1-2012
Q2-2011
 . 
 .
 .
```

I want to sort this column by having all the the quarters of year 2011 then 2012 and so on and so forth. However when I try to do the normal sort it gives the Q1 of all the years then Q2..till Q4. Please help me sort the column year wise.
Thank  you

Comment: Add another column (which you could hide if it really bothers you), with the formula: `=RIGHT(A1,4) & "-" & LEFT(A1,2)`. I assume here that in `A1` you have the quarter values. Then sort on that new column. Would this solve your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a column with text "Q1-2011"  Here's how to do the sort.

1. Open up the spreadsheet.
2. Do you see the column with the "Q1-2011" in it? (I'm going to call this column A)  Select the column header to the right of it.  Right Click, insert. Do this again, Right Click, insert. This step creates two empty columns to the right of your original "Q1-2011".
3. Copy the entire column "Q1-2011" to the left most of the two columns you just created. (that would be column B.  At this point column C is blank)
4. Select the column you just filled with the copied data, with a left mouse click.  The selected area should be highlighted in blue.
5. On top menu in Excel, choose the Data tab, then choose Text to columns
6. You should see a pop up box.  Select Delimited --> Next.  Select Other and in the box add `-` the minus sign --> Next, and finished.

[image: TextToColumn Popup]

7. Now sort your data.  Select the entire sheet.  (left click, area to be sorted will be in blue.)  Choose Data Tab then select Sort.  You will see a popup box.  Sort by column C (the year) first, then add a level (see the button?) than sort by column B (the quarter)
8. Now hide columns B and C .

All done!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'd have to create another column to bring back a date in the quarter and then filter on that.